# Objective C - Call Custom iOS 12 Shortcut from Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parameters, shortcut

Is it possible to call a custom iOS12 Shortcut from with an iOS app written in Objective C?

I can see that you can donate a shortcut so that shortcuts can access parts of your app, but I'm trying to find any information on running an external custom shortcut and passing it information (i.e. NSString) from within my app.

No mention in any searches that I could find so far.

Anyone?

Comment: Maybe the app you want to call supports some custom url scheme. Then it would be about opening a url.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, this is what I ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer I was looking for. I'm Including my code here in case anyone else is looking for the same thing. Only problem is that the shortcuts app comes to the foreground. It would be nicer if it stayed in the background for my use.

```
//Name of the shortcut
NSString *myShortcut = @"Weather%20please";

//Create a URL Scheme to run a shortcut
NSString *shortcutURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"shortcuts://run-shortcut?name=%@", myShortcut];

//Open the URL
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:shortcutURL] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

If you need to include a parameter then use the following:

```
shortcuts://run-shortcut?name=[name]&input=[input]
```

I found this post to be of help in finding the answer I was looking for:
https://medium.com/@darshitshah/shortcut-deeplinking-for-ios-developer-64f75171c7de